# Python decorators and Flask routes: Can I decorate a function call or only a function definition?

Tags: python, flask, routes, decorator

I have a Flask route:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**Can I define my function elsewhere and decorate the function call instead?**

```
from module import index    

@app.route('/')
index()
```

I don't have a fundamental grasp of decorators and I'm also not sure if there is something Flask-specific about the standard behavior so thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't decorate function call in that case, but you can define new function which call required:

```
from module import index    

@app.route('/')
def new_index()
    return index()
```

Or even simple, as @JoranBeasley proposed:

```
app.route("/")(index)
```

Comment: or just `app.route("/",index)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley What would that look like if the route took an argument? Something like `app.route('/profile/<profile_id>/', 'profile', profile, profile_id)`?

Comment: no ... just like normal `app.route('/profile/<profile_id>/',profile_fn)`  I sometimes make a urls.py that does this sort of thing ... but then I find myself just recreating django ...

Comment: I believe it would need to be `app.route("/")(index)` or [`app.add_url_rule("/", "index", index)`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule)